# expected value of Brownian Motion

Tags: expected-value, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Suppose I have a brownian motion $B(t)$,

how to calculate the Expected value of $B(t)$ to the power of any integer value $n$?

Intuition told me should be all 0. But how to make this calculation?

Comment: If by "Brownian motion" you mean a random walk, then this may be relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103142/expected-value-of-random-walk

Comment: The marginal distribution for the Brownian motion (as usually defined) at any given (pre)specified time $t$ is a normal distribution ... Write down that normal distribution and you have the answer

Comment: "$B(t)$" is just an alternative notation for a random variable having a Normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $t$ (which is just a standard Normal distribution that has been scaled by $t^{1/2}$).  The expectation of a power is called a *moment*.  You can find the moments of a unit-variance distribution all worked out at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/176702/how-to-calculate-the-expected-value-of-a-standard-normal-distribution/176814#176814.  The $n^\text{th}$ moment of $B(t)$ therefore is found by multiplying those answers by $t^{n/2}$.

Comment: Certainly not all powers are 0, otherwise $B(t)=0$! It will however be zero for all odd powers since the normal distribution is symmetric about 0.