# A problem about Multivariate Normal Distribution

Tags: self-study, expected-value, multivariate-normal-distribution

*$(X,Y,Z)$* is a multivariate normal distribution. Calculate  $E[X^2YZ]$

I'm finding an approach for this problem. I'm not sure if it is possible to assume
$E[X^2YZ] = E[X^2]E[Y]E[Z]$

Comment: Do you have the covariance matrix?

Comment: You also need to know the means.  The general solution for a bivariate Normal is given at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/583124/how-to-compute-this-moment-of-a-bivariate-normal-distribution/583152#583152.  The technique obviously extends to more variables.  Alternatively, since $X^2YZ=X^2((Y+Z)/2)^2-X^2((Y-Z)/2)^2$ and linear combinations of multivariate Normals are also multivariate Normal, you can  apply the bivariate solution separately to the bivariate Normal variables $(X, (Y+Z)/2)$ and $(X,(Y-Z)/2).$ If either $\mu_Y$ or $\mu_Z$ is zero, the answer trivially is zero.

Comment: It only mentions that $(X,Y,Z)$ is a Gaussian vector,which I understand it's a multivariate normal distribution. Covariance matrix isn't given. So maybe there is an error with this problem

Comment: There's not necessarily an error in the problem statement: it just means the answer will depend on the nine parameters of the distribution.